# Subscribe calling twice and adding take or pipe not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am passing a data from one component to another using observables and subscribing it in constructor using below code :

```
this.api.updateListData$.subscribe((data : any) => {
   this.updateTaskList(data);
});
```

it is getting called twice, and when I added pipe and take in the code, it is not getting called even once

```
this.api.updateListData$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data : any) => {
   this.updateTaskList(data);
});
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, please suggest any solution to it.

Comment: What is `this.api.updateListData$`?

Comment: How do you pass data to updateListData?

Comment: I am passing data of updateListData from another component, I have send true value as like below code :-
  this.api.updateListData(true);

Comment: (service.ts file) 

  private messageSource2= new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  updateListData$=this.messageSource2.asObservable();

Comment: updateListData(data: any){
    this.messageSource2.next(data);
  }